# Target integer only values within dataframe and round to nearest even integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to round the values to the nearest even number within a dataframe.

**Data**

```
ID  Q121 Q221 Q321 Q421 Q122 Q222 Q322 Q422
AA  5.9  9.5  6.6  11.4 6.8  7.8  4.5  8.6
BB  8.5  6.5  3.1  5.3  7.2  8.1  5.3  8.7
```

**Desired**

```
ID  Q121 Q221 Q321 Q421 Q122 Q222 Q322 Q422
AA  6.0  10.0 6.0  12.0 6.0  8.0  4.0  8.0
BB  8.0  6.0  4.0  6.0  8.0  8.0  6.0  8.0
```

**Doing**

```
df.set_index(['ID']).round(df/2)*2
```

I only want to target the columns that contain values in them, so I am indexing the first column.
I am still researching, any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `df.iloc[:,1:].div(2).round() * 2`

Comment: thank you @Quang Hoang, but I am getting type error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'  - perhaps I need to convert?

Comment: That's probably your data is string. So `df.iloc[:,1:].astype(float).div(2).round()`.

Comment: `2` is not the nearest even integer to `3.1`

Comment: right I updated disregard that @mozway

Answer (score 1):

```
df.select_dtypes('number').round()
```